# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when adding a UITableView as SubView

Tags: ios, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

When i've created a UITableView in the code en add it as a subview in the code it is all working fine. There is green tableview visible.
Example of the code i've created for that.

```
- (void)getOverviewTable
{
  // Adding the TableView
  OverviewTableViewController *overviewTableViewController = [[OverviewTableViewController alloc] init];
  UITableView *overviewTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))];

  // Set the datasource and delegete will come here

  [overviewTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

  [self.view addSubview:overviewTableView];
}
```

But after i've set the DataSource and the Delegete for the TableView i will receive a warning.
The code in total for reaching it is as follows:

```
- (void)getOverviewTable
{
  // Adding the TableView
  OverviewTableViewController *overviewTableViewController = [[OverviewTableViewController alloc] init];
  UITableView *overviewTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))];

  // Set the datasource and delegete will come here
  [overviewTableView setDataSource:overviewTableViewController];
  [overviewTableView setDelegate:overviewTableViewController];

  [overviewTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

  [self.view addSubview:overviewTableView];
}
```

The most of the time it is just an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, but sometimes it shows me the following error.

```
[UITransitionView numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

The 'OverViewTableViewController' is replaced by just an empty UITableViewController class but the error is still showing up.

(Point of the application is an fullscreen takeover which has to be swiped away to see the tableview underneath it)

Edit:

The function is called from the viewDidLoad function

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"]]];

  // Setting the home takeover
  [self setHomeTakeOver];

  // Wait one seconde before we load the tableview
  [self getOverviewTable];
  //[self performSelector:@selector(getOverviewTable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

Comment: what is OverviewTableViewController *overviewTableViewController?

Comment: are u sure that u are implementing the `Datasource` and `Delegates` in `OverViewTableViewController`

Comment: This is usually due to calling methods on object that has been deallocated. If memory the object points to is not already allocated by some other object you receive bad access. If it is allocated for instance by some UITransitionView it will report unrecognized selector. Try analyzer tool, it might find you the overreleased object if that is the case.

Comment: Why dont you make `OverviewTableViewController` instance as ivar, instead of local variable? Datasource assignment will not make synchronous calls to all methods, it will execute the function and then call table view methods. Till that time, the `OverviewTableViewController` object will be out of scope if not retained. Remember both `delegate` and `datasource` properties of `UITableView` are `assign` and not `retain`

Comment: I'm trying to make it an ivar and have placed the following code in the .h file. `@property (nonatomic, assign) OverviewTableViewController *overviewTableViewController;`. In the .m file in the function i'm trying to add `self.overviewTableViewController = [[OverviewTableViewController alloc] init];` but that gives me the warning `Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released after assignment`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I think is you have your project ARC enabled and from your code segment what i understand is that `overviewTableViewController` is released through ARC as soon as it leaves the scope of the function `getOverviewTable`. So, better declare the overviewTableViewController in .h file(`@property (nonatomic, strong) OverviewTableViewController *overviewTableViewController;` ). 
If you do this then the code will look like this
in .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) OverviewTableViewController *overviewTableViewController;
```

//// I have strong reference rather than assign

in .m file

```
- (void)getOverviewTable
{
  // Adding the TableView
  overviewTableViewController = [[OverviewTableViewController alloc] init]; //// I have made  overviewTableViewController as member variable.
  UITableView *overviewTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))];

  // Set the datasource and delegete will come here
  [overviewTableView setDataSource:overviewTableViewController];
  [overviewTableView setDelegate:overviewTableViewController];

  [overviewTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

  [self.view addSubview:overviewTableView];
  [overviewTableView reloadData];
}
```

Also be sure that OverviewTableViewController has implemented the datasource methods like

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Thanks, i've made it an ivar as a retain. I'm not receiving any errors now. But is it still not working. I've to call `[self.overviewTableViewController viewDidLoad];` before it works. Is that correct?

Comment: @R. Schaaphuizen I have edited my answer, please check. I think your tableView datasource methods are not getting fired up. So to make the tableView call its datasource methods i have added [overviewTableView reloadData]; method at end of - (void)getOverviewTable function. Please check and let me know if problem still persists.

Comment: still does not work, I have to call the viewDidLoad to make it work, I also have another problem with setting the height of an UITextView in a custom cell. I don't know if it has anything to do with this problem.

Comment: from where are you calling this - (void)getOverviewTable function

Comment: That is called from the 'viedDidLoad'. I've made an edit to the post with this function.

Comment: what if you all the  - (void)getOverviewTable function after some delay?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32151/discussion-between-ironman-and-r-schaaphuizen)

Comment: Finally got it, Credits to @ironman which helped me with filling the data which is used for the rows before calling the reloadData function. The original function was not triggered from the DataSource class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
  [overviewTableView setDataSource:self];
  [overviewTableView setDelegate:self];
```

Also confirm to `tableviewDelegate` and `datasource` and implement following methods.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I want the datasource and delegate to be a different class because the same tableview data is used elsewhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to implement this method.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
}
```

Comment: In which file should I implement this function, in the OverViewTableViewController?

Comment: @R.Schaaphuizen Yes. Basically in viewController which is your tableView's datasource.

Comment: put a break point in this method and check method is executing or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the table view controller's tableView property to overviewTableView.  I don't know off hand if the UITableViewController must have that property set.

```
- (void)getOverviewTable
{
  // Adding the TableView
  OverviewTableViewController *overviewTableViewController = [[OverviewTableViewController   alloc] init];
  UITableView *overviewTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(0, 0,     self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))];

  // Set the datasource and delegete will come here
  [overviewTableView setDataSource:overviewTableViewController];
  [overviewTableView setDelegate:overviewTableViewController];

  //THIS IS THE NEW LINE
  //a UITableViewController needs to know UITableView that it's managing
  [overviewTableViewController setTableView:overviewTableView]; 

  [overviewTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

  [self.view addSubview:overviewTableView];
}
```